# Sitemap "Couldn't fetch" in Google Search Console

Tags: seo, google-search-console, sitemap

I've submitted a sitemap to my website and Google Search Console status is "Couldn't fetch". I've had my xml verified by [XML Validation](https://www.xmlvalidation.com/), and my xml is also publicly available to be viewed.

[Google's support website](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7451001?hl=en) suggested troubleshooting "Couldn't find status" with the URL inspection tool. I wasn't able to find anything useful from that asides that my sitemap hasn't been crawled. See the screenshot below:

[image]

[image]

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<urlset xmlns="http://sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <url>
    <loc>https://simplyharmonica.com/</loc>
    <lastmod>2019-03-27</lastmod>
    <changefreq>yearly</changefreq>
    <priority>1.0</priority>
  </url>

  <url>
    <loc>https://simplyharmonica.com/harmonica-for-beginner</loc>
    <lastmod>2019-03-27</lastmod>
    <changefreq>yearly</changefreq>
    <priority>0.8</priority>
  </url>

  <url>
    <loc>https://simplyharmonica.com/different-types</loc>
    <lastmod>2019-03-27</lastmod>
    <changefreq>yearly</changefreq>
    <priority>0.8</priority>
  </url>

  <url>
    <loc>https://simplyharmonica.com/blues-diatonic-harmonica</loc>
    <lastmod>2019-03-27</lastmod>
    <changefreq>yearly</changefreq>
    <priority>0.8</priority>
  </url>

  <url>
    <loc>https://simplyharmonica.com/blues-diatonic-harmonica</loc>
    <lastmod>2019-03-27</lastmod>
    <changefreq>yearly</changefreq>
    <priority>0.8</priority>
  </url>

  <url>
    <loc>https://simplyharmonica.com/chromatic</loc>
    <lastmod>2019-03-27</lastmod>
    <changefreq>yearly</changefreq>
    <priority>0.8</priority>
  </url>

  <url>
    <loc>https://simplyharmonica.com/holder</loc>
    <lastmod>2019-03-27</lastmod>
    <changefreq>yearly</changefreq>
    <priority>0.8</priority>
  </url>

  <url>
    <loc>https://simplyharmonica.com/hohner</loc>
    <lastmod>2019-03-27</lastmod>
    <changefreq>yearly</changefreq>
    <priority>0.8</priority>
  </url>

  <url>
    <loc>https://simplyharmonica.com/lee-oskar</loc>
    <lastmod>2019-03-27</lastmod>
    <changefreq>yearly</changefreq>
    <priority>0.8</priority>
  </url>

  <url>
    <loc>https://simplyharmonica.com/marine-band</loc>
    <lastmod>2019-03-27</lastmod>
    <changefreq>yearly</changefreq>
    <priority>0.8</priority>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

EDIT: [Solution found here](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2017/09/26/how-to-build-a-serverless-seo-friendly-react-blog/) and also adding `www.` before sitemaps.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Additional problem: Every node in your `sitemap.xml` is also using `http://www...` and the location is wrong.

Sitemap:

```
<loc>http://www.example.com/different-types</loc> (note the "s")
```

Original address:

```
http://example.com/different-type
```

Comment: Hi Marius, thanks for your answer. I've removed the www. and still have the same problem (new xml reflected in my question). My URL also is different-types, maybe I misspelled it when first asking the question.

Comment: Next check: I would try to create a `robots.txt` and point to the `sitemap.xml`. Or try [trigger a sitemap submit via GET](https://www.google.com/ping?sitemap=https://example.com/sitemap.xml) - i did it.

Comment: Sorry for that, but. Did you ever typed in: [https://simplyharmonica.com/hohner](https://simplyharmonica.com/hohner) ? It does not work. Only via the internal js-navigation. Please check your plugins or your full cms. This is not user and not search engine friendly. This is a bigger issue than submitting a sitemap...

Comment: Thanks for the help! Fixed the link issue by following steps on this blog and added www. before the sitemap. Both of those fixed the problem!

Answer (score 2):

Probably the search console can't fetch you sitemap because it's under the "**www.**" domain, while the console is looking for a sitemap under the "non-www." domain.

Try to set a 301 redirect on one of the domain and to the domain version you prefer or make Google fetch the "**www.**" domain by making a new property under that domain and not the "**non-www.**"

Comment: Hi Giamme, thanks for your answer. I've removed the www. and still have the same problem (new xml reflected in my question). I don't have a preference between www and non-www. I also have another propety that doesn't have any prefixes (image updated in original answer) and that also doesn't work

Comment: As Marius pointed out down below there's a bigger problem. Try to check if you have any redirection problems.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Fixed the link issue by following steps on this blog and added www. before the sitemap. Both of those fixed the problem!